# Why OnPost is not getting hit without "@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" in ASP.NET Core version 5.0

Tags: httprequest, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using ASP.NET CORE version 5.0, and I'm using razor pages for my web UI. I was having a problem hitting a simple OnPost method with the following structure in HTML:

```
@page

@model EmptyOne.Web.Pages.SaysHelloModel
@{
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter the name you wanna say hello two ;)</p>

    <form method="post">
        Search term:
        <input name="nameToHello" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    @* some logic to say hello if model is not null... *@
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my page model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace EmptyOne.Web.Pages
{
    public class SaysHelloModel : PageModel
    {
        public string guysName { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }

        
        public IActionResult OnPost(string nameToHello)
        {
            guysName = nameToHello;
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

It returns an HTTP 400 status core and a blank page when I try to hit it, but for some reason, when I add this helper:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

It works fine!

The final and working view(i didn't change anything in the page model class):

```
@page

@model EmptyOne.Web.Pages.SaysHelloModel
@{
}
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter the name you wanna say hello two ;)</p>

    <form method="post">
        Search term:
        <input name="nameToHello" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    @* some logic to say hello if model is not null... *@
</body>
</html>
```

So can anyone explain to me why that is? I looked up an ASP.NET Core version 5.0 code example and saw this helper. Am I using this helper in any way? What does it have to do with sending an HTTP post request to my page handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor Pages includes an [anti-CSRF mechanism, known as request verification](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification), by default. It relies on a token that is applied to a hidden form field being sent with each POST request. The hidden form field is generated automatically by the [form tag helper](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/form-tag-helper). If you omit the token value from your post, for example by disabling the form tag helper, the framework returns a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't fully understand the logic here. Cause the helper reference isn't there in the first place. Shouldn't it be added on razor-page creation time if it's something that the lack of it makes an HTTP post request fail?
Or maybe you mean I'm not using the other tag-helpers, which makes automatic forms for models; therefore, I should add this helper. Did I get it right?

Comment: The `addTagHelper` call should go into a ViewImports file so that it isn't needed in every page: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/viewimports